# Rails layout without yield statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was reading code of linuxfr.org, a rails open source project. I am surprised that the following code from application.html.haml does not have a "yield" statement (without any symbol associated with it), so how will the content be rendered with the layout?

https://github.com/linuxfrorg/linuxfr.org/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml

For example, how does the layout merge with the show view file?

https://github.com/linuxfrorg/linuxfr.org/blob/master/app/views/wiki_pages/show.html.haml

Comment: @engineersmnky but that yield :layout, which I assume only yield content_for :layout. What about the other content that does not have any labels associated with it? For example, my second link?

Answer (score 0):

By default, yield is the same as yield :layout. Rails assumes that all code inside view files are content_for :layout if not specified otherwise.